# Database migration from oracle to postgresql stored procedure call exception while using simpleJdbcCall

Tags: java, postgresql, oracle, spring-boot

I'm trying to database migration from oracle to `PostgreSQL` but facing an issue while call the procedure using PostgreSQL database but getting this error, when I tried to oracle database that time the code working fine could you tell me the solution where I am wrong thanks in advance.

```java
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);
simpleJdbcCall.withSchemaName(schema).withProcedureName("PRC_SERVICES");
simpleJdbcCall.declareParameters(new SqlParameter("P_ID", Types.VARCHAR), 
    new SqlParameter("SERVICE_ID",Types.NUMERIC), new SqlParameter("TEMP_ID",Types.NUMERIC), 
    new SqlParameter("ENABLE",Types.VARCHAR), new SqlParameter("REMOVE",Types.VARCHAR),
    new SqlParameter("URL", Types.VARCHAR), new SqlOutParameter("STATUS",Types.NUMERIC),
    new SqlOutParameter("MSG",Types.VARCHAR));
queryParams = baseTransformation.getParamMapForUserServiceProcedure(queryParams);
resultsMap = simpleJdbcCall.execute(queryParams);
result = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(resultsMap.get("P_STATUS")));
```

The exception

> [INFO ] 2021-08-31 22:44:27.628 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] UserServiceImpl
>
> - Action=updateUserService Request={enable=Y, thermostat_id=64, serviceid=3, userid=1, remove=Y} [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:27.661
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] SimpleJdbcCall - Added declared parameter for
>   [PRC_SERVICES]: P_ID [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:27.661
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] SimpleJdbcCall - Added declared parameter for
>   [PRC_SERVICES]: SERVICE_ID [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:27.661
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] SimpleJdbcCall - Added declared parameter for
>   [PRC_SERVICES]: TEMP_ID [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:27.661
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] SimpleJdbcCall - Added declared parameter for
>   [PRC_SERVICES]: ENABLE [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:27.661
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] SimpleJdbcCall - Added declared parameter for
>   [PRC_SERVICES]: REMOVE [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:27.662
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] SimpleJdbcCall - Added declared parameter for
>   [PRC_SERVICES]: URL [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:27.662
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] SimpleJdbcCall - Added declared parameter for
>   [PRC_SERVICES]: STATUS [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:27.662
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] SimpleJdbcCall - Added declared parameter for
>   [PRC_SERVICES]: MSG [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:27.662
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] SimpleJdbcCall - JdbcCall call not compiled
>   before execution - invoking compile [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:27.667
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from
>   DataSource [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:40.893 [http-nio-8080-exec-2]
>   CallMetaDataProviderFactory - Using
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.PostgresCallMetaDataProvider
>   [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:40.893 [http-nio-8080-exec-2]
>   CallMetaDataProvider - Retrieving metadata for
>   null/mz_ods/prc_services [WARN ] 2021-08-31 22:44:41.868
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] CallMetaDataProvider - Error while retrieving
>   metadata for procedure columns: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
>   Cannot cast to boolean: "2" [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:41.868
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to
>   DataSource [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:41.868 [http-nio-8080-exec-2]
>   SimpleJdbcCall - Compiled stored procedure. Call string is [{call
>   mz_ods.prc_services()}] [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:41.869
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] SimpleJdbcCall - SqlCall for procedure
>   [PRC_SERVICES] compiled [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:41.869
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] CallMetaDataContext - Unable to locate the
>   corresponding IN or IN-OUT parameter for "SERV_REMOVE" in the
>   parameters used: [] [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:41.869
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] CallMetaDataContext - Unable to locate the
>   corresponding IN or IN-OUT parameter for "SERV_ENABLE" in the
>   parameters used: [] [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:41.869
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] CallMetaDataContext - Unable to locate the
>   corresponding IN or IN-OUT parameter for "USER_ID" in the parameters
>   used: [] [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:41.869 [http-nio-8080-exec-2]
>   CallMetaDataContext - Unable to locate the corresponding IN or IN-OUT
>   parameter for "SERVICE_ID" in the parameters used: [] [DEBUG]
>   2021-08-31 22:44:41.869 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] CallMetaDataContext -
>   Unable to locate the corresponding IN or IN-OUT parameter for
>   "THERMOSTAT_ID" in the parameters used: [] [DEBUG] 2021-08-31
>   22:44:41.869 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] CallMetaDataContext - Matching
>   [SERV_REMOVE, SERV_ENABLE, USER_ID, SERVICE_ID, THERMOSTAT_ID,
>   REPORT_URL] with [] [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:41.869
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] CallMetaDataContext - Found match for []
>   [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:41.870 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] SimpleJdbcCall
> - The following parameters are used for call {call mz_ods.prc_services()} with {} [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:41.870
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] JdbcTemplate - Calling stored procedure [{call
>   mz_ods.prc_services()}] [DEBUG] 2021-08-31 22:44:41.870
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from
>   DataSource

Comment: The code sample you posted and the exception messages don't appear to be related. One is for `USER_SERVICES` and the other for `PRC_SERVICES`.

Comment: Cannot cast to boolean: "2" is the error. But I can't see a boolean parameter.

Comment: for changing name while posting code but real scenario prc_services its procedure name i am using and getting above exception